# Bash - Delete tab-delimited files in a directory that have only one column

Tags: bash

This is a weird question, but I have some files in a directory that are supposed to represent tables/data frames. All the files have one column (that corresponds to the primary key of that table). Then some of them have additional columns. I want to delete all the files that have only one column (i.e. no information). How would I go about doing that?

Example:

`file1`.txt`

```
Probe_ID    GSM132623   GSM132624
1007_s_at   2837.69027061651    2569.91309822531
1053_at 201.081555674069    262.183863416559
117_at  210.403458841772    298.823864999618
121_at  1336.98480463819    1302.96339762767
1255_g_at   70.4408895702285    79.4993012107624
1294_at 464.670062349198    419.035541864715
1316_at 125.550889354316    138.930668105088
1320_at 262.68745143115 208.905917842229
1405_i_at   13.6321130349956    17.7600809690828
```

`file2.txt`

```
Probe_ID
100_g_at
1000_at
1001_at
1002_f_at
1003_s_at
1004_at
1005_at
1006_at
1007_s_at
```

In this case, I'd like to delete `file2.txt` from my directory.

Edit: Oh all the files will have the form `file*.txt`. So I only want to look through those files. Not the other ones in my directory.

Comment: Use `grep -l -v $'\t' file*.txt` to get a list of all the files that don't have a `TAB` in them. Use that as the list of files to delete.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I had absolutely no idea how to proceed with this though. My Bash skills are subpar. I was thinking that I'd use the `cut -f2` command on all the file*.txt files, and pipe it to `wc -l` to see which files had 0 lines, but I though that was a little more complicated than it should've been.

Comment: `grep -lv '\t' file*.txt | xargs rm`

Comment: Instead of `grep -lv`, one can use `grep -L` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @dibery not all greps are GNU grep

Answer (score 1):

You can try any of the below options:

**Option I**

Get the number of columns in the first line with awk and delete the all the files matching with the pattern `file*.txt` if the count of columns is equal to `1`

```
for i in file*.txt; do cols=$(awk -F'\t' '{print NF; exit}' "$i"); if [ $cols -eq 1 ]; then rm -f "$i"; fi; done
```

**Option II**

Get the number of columns in the first line with `head -1 "$i" | tr '\t' '\n' | wc -l` and delete the all the files matching with the pattern `file*.txt` if the count of columns is equal to `1`

```
for i in file*.txt; do cols=$(head -1 "$i" | tr '\t' '\n' | wc -l); if [ $cols -eq 1 ]; then rm -f "$i"; fi; done
```

Comment: OP wants to delete files with only one column. You need to negate the logic. In addition, it would be better to say `for i in file*.txt` to narrow down target files.

Comment: Note that the `for var in "file-glob"` pattern is considered harmful as it *will fail* if you have spaces (or more precisely IFS characters) in any file name. There is no reason to not *always* use the `ls "file-glob" | while read var;` pattern.

Comment: An explanation would be helpful. As would splitting the code over multiple lines would be.

Comment: The basic jist of using awk is perfect here.